# how to post a new comment through a method in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-comments

I am using 'django_comments' for commenting in my site. Now i want to post a new comment via a method in my 'views.py'.

I searched and only found posting comments using {{ forms }} in templates.

So how can i post a new comment through a method. 
Please help me.. and thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. The user fills in the form in your template, submits it to your view, which then processes it and saves it. What are you aiming to achieve?

Comment: i  want to create a post without forms. i mean i want  comment to create automatically.

Comment: Do you mean with Ajax? Because you will always need form fields like inputs or textareas?

Comment: Can you please explain bit more what you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a form, or a post request for that matter. All you need to do is create an instance of the [comment model](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/django_comments/models.py#L51) which you can do via Django's ORM.

To do this, you would need to have all of the necessary parameters the model expects, but it's as simple as:

```
comment = Comment.objects.create(**params)
```